# How to remove whitespaces in Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a problem with Bootstrap Carousel - I want it to be 100% width, from edge to edge, but I can't get rid of small whitespaces on the left and right (margins?). I'he already tried everything: borders, margins, paddings, outlines in a different park of code (images, divs, bootstrap.css) - nothing helps.  Any clues?
[Here's what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPB5q.png)

Here is part of my code:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style="">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: none; ">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/back_1.JPG" alt="Chania" style="min-width:100%; margin: none; padding: none;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/back_2.jpg" alt="Chania" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/back_3.jpg" alt="Flower" style="width:100%;" >
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/back_4.jpg" alt="Flower" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white space on either side of your carousel is coming from the `container` class, which adds `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px`. While you could overwrite this, it would make more sense to simply remove the class from your main `.container` `<div>` element.

Also, note that `<div>` elements are `100%` with by default, so you don't actually need this outer `<div>` container at *all*; you can simply start your carousel with `<div id="myCarousel">`, as is shown in the following example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style="">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: none; ">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Chania" style="min-width:100%; margin: none; padding: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Chania" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Flower" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Flower" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, I was looking for solution a few hours, but didn't noticed this `container` class.

Comment: It's an in-built Bootstrap class, which is useful for the default Bootstrap 'feel' of being a bit offset. If you don't want it, you're more than welcome to remove it :)

Comment: Age u beauty...Geek

Answer (score 0):

same problem here but the code solution above didn't work for me... When i removed the column (using bootstrap 4.4) my small images didn't got fullscreen when i maximized my window. The solution was here to add a css class i called .nomargin with margin and padding set to 0.
I added this class right after col-12 class. So my code looks like this:

```html
     <!-- Header Carousel -->
      <header class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 nomargin">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9515_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9629_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive" src="https://www.kijkrond.in/stationroeselare/" alt="..." >
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```